# What is this function doing?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
parseResponse = (response, cb) -> 
  output = ''
  response.setEncoding('utf8')
  response.on 'data', (chunk) -> output += chunk
  response.on 'end', ->
    j = JSON.parse(output)
    result = j.results[0]
    cb(result)
```

I'm trying to understand what this is doing and why it is necessary in a module I'm using. The response being passed in is from an http get.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: I do not know the scripting language at all, but I would guess it reads the response in chunks of UTF8 encoded data and when finished, calls the callback function passed in the variable cb with the resulting JSON string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function processes a response (instance of the [`ClientResponse`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.0/api/http.html#http.ClientResponse) class) being received via HTTP.

```
response.setEncoding('utf-8')
```

Indicates the desired transfer encoding (UTF-8). Chunks passed to the `data` event will be sent in this encoding.

```
response.on 'data', (chunk) -> output += chunk
```

Sets up a callback for processing data chunks. Each "chunk" of a string received is appended to the `output` string variable.

```
response.on 'end', ->
```

Sets another callback which acts on the completely transferred data.

```
j = JSON.parse(output)
result = j.results[0]
```

The received data is assumed to be JSON and parsed as such. The first element of the parsed array is retrieved.

```
cb(result)
```

The callback `cb` originally provided to the function is called with this data found in the JSON object.

Comment: Thanks Hans! Why exactly does it need to be done? What form is the response in before it is parsed? Is it just receiving chunked data that is needs to put together?

Comment: At the time of the function's execution, an HTTP response is being expected. It sets up event callbacks which will run as the data flows in. I don't know much about HTTP / TCP, but I'm guessing that the data comes in as raw binary chunks, and setting the desired encoding tells Node to process it as a UTF-8 string.

Comment: Your last assertion is correct. It receives the data, string-chunk by string-chunk, and accumulates each piece in the `output` variable. It does a bit of extra processing and then hands over the data to the callback it was given as a parameter.